# How to get last selected item from chosen multiselect plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-chosen

As the question says, I would like to know how to get the last selected item value from chosen multiselect plugin.

So far I have this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#id').chosen().on('change', function(evt, param) {
            var id1 = this.value;
            var id2 = $("#id").chosen().val();
            var id3 = $('#id', this).filter(':selected:last').val();
            var id4 = $(evt.target).text();

            alert('IDs:' +id1+'-'+id2+'-'+id3+'-'+id4);
    });
});
```

Here is the output:

```
2 - undefined - undefined - [all the values]
```

The first answer is correct (I chose the second value).

But if I later choose the 3rd value or one after the one I chose before, it keeps showing me the first value I chose. However, if I choose a value situated before the first one it works perfectly and I don't know why.

Any help would be great.

Comment: `this.value` is simply the first of all the selected values in the DOM, it has nothing to do with the order that you selected them.

Comment: Yes I can see that Barman, thank you for the clarification. :) Is there a way where we can actually get the last chosen value?

Comment: For a regular multi-select, you could do it with a click handler on all the `<option>` elements. Some modification is probably required with `Chosen`, because the options are replaced with DIVs.

Comment: Ok, thats one way to do it, but for code efficiency isn't there something that can be done with the objects that come from the event? (evt and param)?

Comment: Not that I know of. The object just has the current state of the multiselect, which is just a list of selected elements. The browser doesn't keep track of the order they were selected, why should it?

Comment: I was thinking not so much as the order they were selected rather as the action of the last clicked element :)

Comment: If you bind to the `select`, the element clicked on is not in the event. You have to bind a handler to the options. It's not any less efficient, they're all sharing the same handler function.

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT:**

This should work:

```
$('option').click(function(){
    var option = $(this);
    var str = "";
    $("#id option:selected" ).each(function() {
        if (option.val()==$(this).val()){
            alert (option.val());
        }
    });
});
```

See this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4C4Cm/).

Comment: Thank you Albus Shin for your answer, however the .click function doesn't trigger when it is being clicked. Maybe it has something to do that it is included on a document ready function?